# NullReferenceException only when building and running in android in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, location, location-services

So I have the following code:

```
LongLat[0] = Convert.ToDouble(Input.location.lastData.latitude);
LongLat[1] = Convert.ToDouble(Input.location.lastData.longitude);
if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running) { print("Running"); }
print(LongLat[0]);
```

I define LongLat as a public array:

```
public double[] LongLat = new double[2];
```

When I run this in the unity editor I have no issues ( At a later point i redefine LongLat since obviously the pc has no GPS). But when I build and run on android I get a NullReferenceException on the fourth line, print(LongLat[0]), It is not clear to my why this is happening.

The location services are running.

Here is ouput from adb.

```
07-02 23:48:37.409 20555 20570 I Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
07-02 23:48:37.409 20555 20570 I Unity   :   at Location.GetLocation () [0x00065] in F:\Dropbox\Dropbox\UnityGames\Tagger\Assets\Location.cs:205
07-02 23:48:37.409 20555 20570 I Unity   :   at Location+<Start>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00233] in F:\Dropbox\Dropbox\UnityGames\Tagger\Assets\Location.cs:82
07-02 23:48:37.409 20555 20570 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00028] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17
```

If I comment out

```
LongLat[0] = Input.location.lastData.latitude;
LongLat[1] = Input.location.lastData.longitude;
```

and use:

```
LongLat[0] = 55.953251f; 
LongLat[1] = 3.188267f;
```

It works fine.

Comment: post the logcat with error flag.

Comment: I added it to the original post, thanks.

Comment: A null reference means that it is trying to access something that doesn't exist. You either forgot to drag something in the editor, or you are a step ahead and have something un-commented that should still be commented. Your code is using something that isn't there.

Comment: It works in the Unity Editor though so something weird must be going on with the android compiler.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is at `print(LongLat[0])`? I really doubt that. I think you should comment that line. You will see that this problem still exist.

Comment: 07-02 23:48:37.409 20555 20570 I Unity   :   at Location.GetLocation () [0x00065] in F:\Dropbox\Dropbox\UnityGames\Tagger\Assets\Location.cs:205

Line 205 is print(LongLat[0]). The problem isn't the print statement but something to do with the location service.

Comment: I updated the original question to show that problem is clearly something to do with the location service part.

Answer (score 1):

So i managed to solve by not putting Input.location.lastData in a array but rather just using it directly.

I still don't know why putting in an array was so troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize location services like [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html)?